How can I extract only selected properties/nodes from this json string?
I'm trying to deserialize this string to put the data in a table (I'm using Blazor), I only need the ItemSections' ItemIds (I need to put all of them in the table actually), the rest of it can be disposed of. Thing is I'm trying to make it work but I'm a bit stuck.
This is the string :
{
   "id":6,
   "description":"Accounting",
   "position":0,
   "enabled":true,
   "itemSections":[
      {
         "itemId":7,
         "sectionId":6,
         "item":{
            "id":7,
            "type":2,
            "description":"ctb_1",
            "notes":"",
            "shortDescription":"ctb_1",
            "code":"",
            "enabled":true,
            "guid":null,
            "itemSections":[
               null
            ],
            "layouts":[
               
            ],
            "scopes":[
               
            ],
            "users":[
               
            ],
            "bookmarks":[
               
            ],
            "tenantId":null
         },
         "section":null,
         "position":0
      },
      {
         "itemId":8,
         "sectionId":6,
         "item":{
            "id":8,
            "type":2,
            "description":"ctb_2",
            "notes":"",
            "shortDescription":"ctb_2",
            "code":"string",
            "enabled":true,
            "guid":null,
            "itemSections":[
               null
            ],
            "layouts":[
               
            ],
            "scopes":[
               
            ],
            "users":[
               
            ],
            "bookmarks":[
               
            ],
            "tenantId":null
         },
         "section":null,
         "position":0
      },
      {
         "itemId":9,
         "sectionId":6,
         "item":{
            "id":9,
            "type":2,
            "description":"TIMELINE ADEMPIMENTI",
            "notes":"s",
            "shortDescription":"TIMELINE ADEMPIMENTI",
            "code":"string",
            "enabled":true,
            "guid":null,
            "itemSections":[
               null
            ],
            "layouts":[
               
            ],
            "scopes":[
               
            ],
            "users":[
               
            ],
            "bookmarks":[
               
            ],
            "tenantId":null
         },
         "section":null,
         "position":0
      }
   ],
   "users":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Administrator",
         "email":null,
         "role":1,
         "login":"string",
         "password":"string",
         "enabled":true,
         "canImpersonate":true,
         "theme":null,
         "layouts":[
            
         ],
         "userFilters":[
            
         ],
         "items":[
            
         ],
         "scopes":[
            
         ],
         "sections":[
            null
         ],
         "bookmarks":[
            
         ],
         "tenantId":null
      }
   ]
}

This is the deserializing, just in case it's useful (items is a GridList) :
result = await url.WithOAuthBearerToken(Token).GetStringAsync();
var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(result);
items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GridList>(jsonDocument.RootElement, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
});

Also the table I'm trying where I'm trying to put all of the data, maybe there is something wrong here too :
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @* headers *@
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Enabled</th>
            <th>Item Sections</th>
            <th>Users</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in items)
        {
            @* dati *@
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td>@item.Position</td>
                <td>@item.Enabled</td>
                <td>@string.Join(", ", item.ItemSections)</td>
                <td>@string.Join(", ", item.Users)</td>
                <td>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="(e => GetId(item.Id)) style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0b2363, #3a0647);">Apri Pagina</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>    

Here's the class I used (yes, the ItemIds I was talking about are not implemented because as I said I'm stuck) :
    public class GridList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public List<string> ItemSections { get; set; }
        public List<string> Users { get; set; }
    }


Does it really not start with a { and end with a }? It seems very odd that you don't receive actual JSON.

It does, I cut it but now that I think about it I also cut other ItemSections... I'll add them one sec

Have you tried paste json as class?

I don't quite get where the problem is. Any error message?

.Deserialize<List<GridList>> - the json shown is not a List.

@JohnWu, If I use that it puts this inside every item section : LoginThing.Pages.Models.Itemsection[0]

Basically, you need to deserialize to a class that matches the structure of the JSON you're deserializing. If you don't care about anything other than itemSections, you can create a class which contains nothing but a property to represent that. (It doesn't help that you've posted snippets of code, but haven't explained why you've got a JsonDocument etc...)

@Fildor you are right, I took the code from the wrong page (I have one with general data and one with specific data), I'll correct it right away

@JonSkeet the I got the JSON document from these :
result = await url.WithOAuthBearerToken(Token).GetStringAsync();
    var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(result);

I'll add it to the post ty

But why use that at all, rather than deserializing straight to a class?

Please add the GridList class

@auburg right on it!

@JonSkeet I realized I could do that later, but I still decided to keep it that way just for good measure, even tho it's quite useless

@Michelle so looking at your GridList class, it doesn't match the json at all: the ItemSections and Users properties are a list of strings - but your json has a list of objects. Have a look at this useful feature of Visual Studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022 to generate c# classes from json

You can read the json as JsonElement and then extract the desired value by traversing to the field, Here is how,
string json = File.ReadAllText("YouFullJson.json");
var element = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));
var sections = element.GetProperty("itemSections").Deserialize<JsonElement[]>();
var ids = sections.Select(o => o.GetProperty("itemId").GetInt32());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",ids));


I had other things to fix other than adding this, but thanks to this I was able to solve the problem, ty so much!
